# How many class types are there in PHP?

Tags: php, class, types

Are abstract and interface kind of class types?

Any else? Interviewer said there should be 8, but I could not find that many.

Thanks.

Comment: Define what a "class type" is or isn't exactly...?

Comment: Please show some evidence you've done some research - what class types have you found so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that the interviewer meant about PHP **Predefined Interfaces and Classes**:

- Traversable
- Iterator
- IteratorAggregate
- Throwable
- ArrayAccess
- Serializable
- Closure
- Generator

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.interfaces.php

Comment: What sets those apart from e.g. StdClass, DateTimeInterface, finfo, Phar, Reflector, SessionHandlerInterface, .....any many more...?

Comment: Btw: Nothing wrong with the answer per se, just (if that's the expected answer): What an irrelevant interview question.

Comment: @VolkerK, of course, stdClass, DateTimeInterface etc. are also in the list of predefined(reserved or standard defined) classes. But I've just tried to recognize the interviewer's "thinking way" (I was interviewed many-many times)